# about throw() in C++

Tags: c++

void MyFunction(int i) throw();

it just tells the compiler that the function does not throw any exceptions.

It can't make sure the function throw nothing, is that right?

So what's the use of throw()

Is it redundant? Why this idea is proposed?

Comment: Consider reading Herb Sutter's article on the topic:  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm  "Moral #1: Never write an exception specification.  Moral #2: Except possibly an empty one, but if I were you I’d avoid even that."

Comment: I like emty exception specifications. But only as long as you do gurantee that it does not throw anything.

Comment: "Why this idea is proposed" -- because it seemed a good idea at the time. ;) C++ has quite a few such "features" that today, are considered Bad Ideas, but which seemed great when they were proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, when the compiler works right, it *is* enforced -- but at run-time, not compile-time.. A function with an empty exception specification will not throw an exception. If something happens that would create an exception escaping from it, will instead call `unexpected()`, which (in turn) calls `abort`. You can use `set_unexpected` to change what gets called, but about all that function is allowed to do is add extra "stuff" (e.g. cleanup) before aborting the program -- it can't return to the original execution path.

That said, at least one major compiler (VC++) parses exception specifications, but does not enforce them, though it can *use* empty exception specifications to improve optimization a little. In this case, an exception specification that isn't followed can/does result in undefined behavior instead of necessarily aborting the program.

Comment: I believe (non-empty) exception specifications were marked deprecated in the latest C++0x draft standard too, so for once, the standard seems to be moving towards aligning itself with VC++, rather than the other way around. :)

Comment: @jalf:I can't find anything indicating that in the current draft (N3000).

Comment: Ah, looks like I was wrong. There was support for deprecating it, but a formal proposal has not been adopted yet: http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/trip-report-october-2008-iso-c-standards-meeting/ - quote: "Near the end of the meeting, we also discussed deprecating export (as I reported earlier) and exception specifications other than throw()-nothing. There seemed to be significant support for deprecating both, and so we’ll probably see a concrete proposal at our next meeting."

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it just tells the compiler that the function does not throw any exceptions.

When the compiler expects possible exceptions, it often has to generate the code in some specific form, which makes it less efficient. It also might have to generate some additional "household" code for the sole purpose of handling exceptions when and if they are thrown.

When you tell the compiler that this function never throws anything, it makes it much easier to the compiler to recognize the situations when all these additional exception-related expenses are completely unnecessary, thus helping the compiler to generate more efficient code.

Note, that if at run time you actually try to throw something out of a function that is declared with `throw()` specification, the exception will not be allowed to leave the function. Instead a so called unexpected exception handler will be invoked, which by default will terminate the program. So, in that  sense it is actually enforced that a `throw()` function does not throw anything.

P.S. Since exception specifications are mostly affecting the *run-time* behavior of the program, in general they might not have any compile time effect. However, this specific exception specification - the empty one `throw()` - is actually recognized by some compilers at *compile time* and does indeed lead to generation of more efficient code. Some people (me included) hold the opinion that the empty exception specification is the only one that is really worth using in the real-life code.

Comment: The ironic part is that the compiler has to generate exception code even if you declare `throw()`, to do the run-time enforcement of which you speak.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I'm talking about generatin efficient code *outside* of a `throw()` function. The enforcing code on the other hand is an internal issue of the function.

Answer (score 1):

> It can't make sure the function throw nothing, is that right?

You are almost there. It is an exception specification. It means that as an implementer you gurantee to your client(s) that this piece of code will not throw an exception. This does not however stop some functions within `MyFunction` to throw and which, if you do not handle them, will bubble up and cause your/client's program in a way you did not intent it to. It does not even mean that you cannot have a `throw` expression inside.

It is best to avoid such specification, until and unless you are absolutely sure that your code *will never* throw -- which is kind of difficult except for very basic functions. See the standard `swap`, pointer assignments etc.

> Is it redundant? Why this idea is proposed?

Not exactly. When properly used, it can be of help to the compiler for optimization purposes. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2006/03/22/558390.aspx) article. [This](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=170) article explains the history behind no-throw well.

Digging a bit more I found [this](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) excellent article from the Boost documentation. A must read. Read about the exception guarantees part.

Comment: AFAIK, the conformant implementation of `throw()`, while allowing to optimize the _caller_ a little bit better, imposes a huge burden on the _callee_, which more than offsets any benefits gained in the caller; so in the end, it's a net loss. That said, your first link is to a blog which describes VC++ specifically, which does not implement `throw()` in a conformant way (rather than forcing the function to terminate if it throws, it just says it's U.B. if it happens), which lets it optimize the caller without paying the price in the callee. Your second link about `nothrow` is unrelated to that.

Comment: Yes, to illustrate that no throw can be helpful. The second link is a bit about the history. Helps?

Comment: @Pavel: the implementation of `throw()` doesn't impose all that huge of a burden. It's equivalent to: `try { function_body(); } catch(...) { (*unexpected)(); }`. Most current compilers can enter a `try` block with little or no overhead, and should be able to do the same in this case. That said, the real use isn't optimization -- it's just that it's almost impossible to make anything exception safe without at least a few primitives that are guaranteed not to throw (anything, ever).

Comment: @Jerry: the burden can be larger than one might expect, as e.g. many compilers won't inline functions with `try` blocks outright.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest exception specifications in the real world have not turned out to be as usfull as envisoned by the origianl designers. Also the differences between C++ runtime checked exception specifications and Java's compile time checked exception specifications has caused a lot of problems.

The currently except norms for exception specifications are:

- Don't use them.
- Unless they are the empty form.

  - Make sure that if you use the empty form gurantee that you actually catch all excetions.

The main problem is that if you have a method with a throw spec. Then somthing it uses changes underneath and now throws new types of exception there is no warning or problem with the code. But at runtime if the exception occurs (the new one that is not in throw spec) then your code will terminate(). To me termination is a last resort and should never happen in a well formed program I would much rather unwind the stack all the way back to main with an exception thus allowing a sliughtly cleaner exit.