# Is it safe to use the throw() suffix on a function containing std::string?

Tags: c++, exception, std, stdstring

I have a member function that doesn't throw anything so i appended the `throw()` suffix to the end of it, indicating that it won't throw any exceptions.

My question is, in the function I make use of several `std::string`, and lets say something goes wrong in the initialization of the `std::string`, and it throws `bad_alloc` or `out_of_range` (or what ever else can go wrong with a std::string).

Is it still safe to still add the `throw()` suffix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [about throw() in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157606/about-throw-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Herb Sutter [says](http://books.google.ru/books?id=_1uD7khOQooC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=Herb%20Sutter%20throw%28%29%20benefit&source=bl&ots=KDkxgVifvT&sig=-qGuDFBjeiMybvMsUz6Mp0_Cmxk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8--ST-Z4hJc6uqq4ggQ&redir_esc=y) that

> exception specifications confer a lot less benefit than they're worth

It can cause more problems than bring benefits. So, you should think twise before doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The exception specification makes a promise about all code which runs inside the function, whether you wrote it or not.

If `std::string` throws from inside your function, that promise is broken, and your program fails. (`std::unexpected` exception, which normally means your program terminates hard)

The `throw()` specification is proper only if:

- Nothing your function does can throw, even indirectly

or

- Your function catches all such exceptions and exits normally (no rethrow).

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

First: the `throw()` specification add a runtime check that the function does not throw, calling `std::unexpected_exception` if the promise is broken, which will terminate the program.

Second: `throw()` is not advised, and has been deprecated in C++11. In C++11 you can use `noexcept` instead (or the more malleable form `noexcept(boolean-expression)`). No runtime check is created, and the behavior is undefined if the function throws.